# Java: Universally accessing resource files regardless of application server

Tags: java, weblogic, wildfly

I'm looking for the 'best practice' way to access resource files (for example a bunch of .xml files) as well as the folder structure in which they reside, regardless of the application server used.

Right now I'm using Wildfly 8 server and I access all `src/main/resources/xxxx` by getting the application real path then using `Paths.get(resourcePath)` as well as `Files.walk(Paths.get(folderPath))` if I want to access a folder's files.

However, I faced a problem when I tried to deploy to Weblogic 12c, because this app server actually takes everything under `WEB-INF/classes` and creates a `.jar` file and adds it to `WEB-INF/lib`. I can still access singular resources using `classLoader.getResource(resourcePath)` but for some reason when I try to create a `new File(Paths.get(resourcePath)` or use `Files.walk(Paths.get(folderPath))` it doesn't seem to be working. It throws an exception saying to file doesn't exist which I'm guessing is because it is not accessible since it is packaged inside a jar file.

I could potentially use `classLoader.getResource(resourcePath)` to access all my resources but unfortunately in my case I cannot know what resources will be available at compile time. I specifically NEED to be able to go through a selected folder's files and subfolders but I haven't found a common way to do it on both app servers, or ALL app servers for that matter.

Bonus points if the solution uses the new File api instead of creating a bunch of FileReaders but I'm ok with that too.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the XML files in a folder `/WEB-INF/xml` and then use the `ServletContext` to obtain a `File` or `Path` for that location.

*Variant 1:*

call `servletContext.getResourceUrl("/WEB-INF/xml")` to obtain a `URL` and convert this URL to a `File` or `Path`. But depending on the server this might return a non-file resource URL, e.g. a `jndi:/` url.

*Variant 2:*

call `servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/xml")` to obtain a file string and convert this URL to a `File` or `Path`.

Comment: That would be a solution yes but I'm reluctant to accept that there is no way to access the resource folders tree from the resources folder where they are actually supposed to be.