# How to configure weblogic variable

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic

I have a webservice in weblogic, and this webservice consumes another service from web. 
today I'm consuming with hardcode string like that

```
String service = "https://myApplication.com/resouces/getClients"
```

I'm looking for something like

```
String service = //go to weblogic find a variable "MyApplication" and return it's content
```

the problem is I have no idea how to create this variable in weblogic and retrive its value in my java application.

Comment: "go to weblogic find a variable" What? Very unclear ...

Comment: In what way is "myApplication" a variable? Are you asking how to [lookup a `String` with JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944828/2970947)?

Comment: I mean how to avoid this hardcode string using weblogic ? 
there is a xml file where can I map some strings?
maybe anything like <Enviroment name="testing" value="myUser" type="java.lang.String"/>

Comment: [Several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32945707/2970947). [Different](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/configureresources.htm#WBAPP209). [Ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808119/java-universally-accessing-resource-files-regardless-of-application-server).